# micro service, reference and foreign keys

Tags: microservices

We have 2 micro services.
account micro service (for registration, verification, etc..).
e-wallets micro service (create a wallet, deposit, withdrawals, etc..).

the application first creates an account and then creates an e-wallet for every verified user.

considering the user identity is manged in the account micro service.

should the wallet service store a reference to the account entity (external-user-id)? or should the account micro service store a reference to the wallet entity (external-wallet-id)?

i am mostly concerned with the account micro service becoming a hub which stores many references. are there any practices i should consider?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to have the client or the creator of the account to generate the account Id using a `guid` then send a message to the account components and the wallet component to create the account and wallet using the generated aacountId and WalletId...

Make sense?